# Check when the cursor changed from arrow to hand cursor (link hand cursor)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, hyperlink

Can someone please help me and give me an example/idea?

I want to determien when the user is standing on a link (the cursor changed from arrow to click hand) and when it happen will show `MessageBox.Show("You are standing on link");`

It needs to be solution that work on all the versions of Windows so please be creative.

EX. The program run on background  (Process is running in loop), and when the user is standing on link any ware (in IE browser for ex.) automatically it pops up a massage ("you are standing on link")

Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET, Winforms, WPF?  What technology are you using?

Comment: What have you yourself tried?

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't specified, I will assume you are using Win Forms.  To capture the hover, simply subscribe to the OnMouseHover event, e.g.

```
yourLinkLabel.MouseHover += yourLinkLabel_MouseHover;

...

private void yourLinkLabel_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("You are standing on link");
}
```

Comment: No, I think you are misunderstand me… The program run on background  (Process is running in loop), and when the user is standing on link any ware (in IE browser for ex.) automatically it pops up a massage ("you are standing on link")

Comment: *That* is not in any way construed in your question.

Comment: Sorry for my bed English, that's not my mother language.. I'll try to explian again... I want to know if there is any event listiner that can recognize when the cursur changed from arrow curser to hand curser... so for example if the user is hover on some link --> the curser changed ot hand --> pop up massege (your hover on link)... is it more understandable?

Answer (score 0):

This comes with my official "Works on my machine" stamp of approval. This may not work for you and is complete guess on my part. Having said that:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct CursorInfo {
    public int Size;
    public int Flags;
    public IntPtr Handle;
    public System.Drawing.Point Position;
}
public class NativeMethods {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetCursorInfo(out CursorInfo info);
}
```

(SNIP)

```
while (true) {
    CursorInfo info = new CursorInfo();
    info.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(info.GetType());
    if (NativeMethods.GetCursorInfo(out info)) {
        if (info.Handle.ToInt32() == 65571) {
            Console.WriteLine("Hand");
        }
    }
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```